# Replace value of one node in array of nodes in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

If I have a column in a table as xml with the following node structure:

```
<ArrayOfPickListObjectBaseModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PickListObjectBaseModel>
    <MasterObjectId>3964405</MasterObjectId>
    <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
  </PickListObjectBaseModel>
  <PickListObjectBaseModel>
    <MasterObjectId>405716</MasterObjectId>
    <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
  </PickListObjectBaseModel>
  <PickListObjectBaseModel>
    <MasterObjectId>5872525</MasterObjectId>
    <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
  </PickListObjectBaseModel>
</ArrayOfPickListObjectBaseModel>
```

I can successfully retrieve all records that have a particular `MasterObjectId`

```
SELECT  p.MyPrimaryKey, 
        m.value('(MasterObjectId)[1]', 'INT')  as MasterObjectID,
        p.MasterObjectIDs
    FROM PickList p
    CROSS APPLY MasterObjectIDs.nodes('//PickListObjectBaseModel') AS t1(m)
    WHERE m.value('(MasterObjectId)[1]', 'INT') = 3964405
```

But how would I replace that number in all matching records if needed?
So in the above example, replace `3964405` with `999`

This is bad syntax, but I think it is similar to:

```
    DECLARE @oldId INT = 13131180;
    DECLARE @newId INT = 99999;

    UPDATE PickList
        SET MasterObjectIDs.modify('replace value of 
    (//PickListObjectBaseModel/MasterObjectId/text()=sql:variable("@oldId"))[1] with sql:variable("@newId")');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great, that you found a solution (voted it up), just some hints:

A dummy table with three rows:

```
DECLARE @DummyTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, Comment VARCHAR(100), MasterObjectIDs XML);
INSERT INTO @DummyTable VALUES
('Your example', N'<ArrayOfPickListObjectBaseModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PickListObjectBaseModel>
    <MasterObjectId>3964405</MasterObjectId>
    <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
  </PickListObjectBaseModel>
  <PickListObjectBaseModel>
    <MasterObjectId>405716</MasterObjectId>
    <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
  </PickListObjectBaseModel>
  <PickListObjectBaseModel>
    <MasterObjectId>5872525</MasterObjectId>
    <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
  </PickListObjectBaseModel>
</ArrayOfPickListObjectBaseModel>'
)
,('More than one target', N'<ArrayOfPickListObjectBaseModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PickListObjectBaseModel>
    <MasterObjectId>3964405</MasterObjectId>
    <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
  </PickListObjectBaseModel>
  <PickListObjectBaseModel>
    <MasterObjectId>405716</MasterObjectId>
    <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
  </PickListObjectBaseModel>
  <PickListObjectBaseModel>
    <MasterObjectId>3964405</MasterObjectId>
    <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
  </PickListObjectBaseModel>
</ArrayOfPickListObjectBaseModel>'
),
('no target', N'<ArrayOfPickListObjectBaseModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PickListObjectBaseModel>
    <MasterObjectId>1111</MasterObjectId>
    <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
  </PickListObjectBaseModel>
  <PickListObjectBaseModel>
    <MasterObjectId>405716</MasterObjectId>
    <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
  </PickListObjectBaseModel>
  <PickListObjectBaseModel>
    <MasterObjectId>5872525</MasterObjectId>
    <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
  </PickListObjectBaseModel>
</ArrayOfPickListObjectBaseModel>');
```

--The variables

```
DECLARE @oldId INT = 3964405;
DECLARE @newId INT = 99999;
```

--I use `xml.exist()`, which is even faster, than your approach to filter target rows:

```
UPDATE @DummyTable
        SET MasterObjectIDs.modify('replace value of 
        (//PickListObjectBaseModel/MasterObjectId[text() = sql:variable("@oldId")]/text())[1]
            with sql:variable("@newId")')
FROM @DummyTable p
WHERE p.MasterObjectIDs.exist('/ArrayOfPickListObjectBaseModel/PickListObjectBaseModel/MasterObjectId[text()=sql:variable("@oldId")]') = 1;
```

--the result

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;         --good the filter hits only 2 rows
SELECT * FROM @DummyTable; --bad, the XML more than one occurances is not edited everywhere...
```

If the id you are looking for, might occur more than once in one XML, your approach will not work for all of them, just for the first...

You can either run your statement in a loop, until `exist()` returns `0`, or you might shredd the XML and rebuild it from scratch like here:

```
WITH UpdateableCTE AS
(
    SELECT p.MasterObjectIds AS Original
          ,B.NewXML
    FROM @DummyTable AS p
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
        (
            SELECT CASE WHEN plo.value(N'(MasterObjectId/text())[1]','int')=@oldId THEN @newId ELSE plo.value(N'(MasterObjectId/text())[1]','int') END AS MasterObjectId
                  ,plo.value(N'(IsSelected/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS IsSelected
            FROM MasterObjectIDs.nodes(N'/ArrayOfPickListObjectBaseModel/PickListObjectBaseModel') AS A(plo)
            FOR XML PATH(N'PickListObjectBaseMode'),ROOT(N'ArrayOfPickListObjectBaseModel'),TYPE
        )
    ) AS B(NewXML)
    WHERE p.MasterObjectIDs.exist('/ArrayOfPickListObjectBaseModel/PickListObjectBaseModel/MasterObjectId[text()=sql:variable("@oldId")]') = 1
)
UPDATE UpdateableCTE SET Original=NewXML;
```

--Only 2 rows are affected

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;         --good the filter hits only 2 rows
SELECT * FROM @DummyTable; --all occurances are switched...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete solution to replace text nodes based on value
The `FROM` part will speed it up as it reduces the number of rows that are affected, otherwise it performs the action on all rows

```
    DECLARE @oldId INT = 13131180;
    DECLARE @newId INT = 99999;

    UPDATE PickList
        SET MasterObjectIDs.modify('replace value of 
        (//PickListObjectBaseModel/MasterObjectId[text() = sql:variable("@oldId")]/text())[1]
            with sql:variable("@newId")')
        FROM PickList p
                CROSS APPLY MasterObjectIDs.nodes('//PickListObjectBaseModel') AS t1(m)
                WHERE m.value('(MasterObjectId)[1]', 'INT') = @oldId
```